# SaaS tool using streaming API - how does authentication work?

Tags: authentication

I'm starting to build a SaaS tool that uses the SF streaming API.
In the past I've worked with the "normal" API and I didn't need any consumer secret / key. I just user user / password and a security token.

Now I understand that I need to provide consumer secret / key. Assuming I will have multiple users, each with their own SF instance - what does it mean in terms of the process to use my tool? Would they need to create a consumer secret / key and provide it
when they login to my tool in order to connect to their SF instance? Or does the secret / key belong to my tool meaning I create them once somehow and the users only need to provide user / password?

Answer (score 0):

The consumer key/secret is used to uniquely identify your app. You do this by creating a [Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_overview.htm&type=5), then using an [OAuth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5) to get an Access Token (and possibly a Refresh Token, if configured to do so). The flows will have the users log in using the Salesforce login (possibly via SSO, etc), then return a valid access token to your app. You will be able to determine the User Id and Organization Id after login using the [Identity URL](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&type=5). At no point will your app need to directly use the user's user name or password to access Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a python library called aiosfstream and the documentation has a user / password option. Is that no longer supported by Salesforce? (https://aiosfstream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)